# Nested v-for only displaying last child of the first element in Vue

Tags: html, vue.js

I'm attempting to use Vue to set up a basic website using Bootstrap grid alignment, since I'd heard that those are both common tools in web development.

This particular setup utilizes a nested items array to print out different styles and colors for each row and column. The current incarnation only renders the last column of the first row, regardless of which one I put in order.

This is my current HTML:

```
    <div id="grid">
        <template v-for="item in items">
            <div class="row" v-for="col in item.object.columns">
                <div :class="`${col.object.cl}`" v-bind:style="{'background-color': `${col.object.style}`}">{{col.object.text}}</div>
            </div>

        </template>
    </div>
```

This is a portion of my JavaScript

```
var grid = new Vue({
            el: "#grid",
            data: {
                //rows 
                items: [
                    {
                        //row object
                        object: {
                            //columns
                            columns: [
                                //column object
                                {
                                    object: {
                                        text: 'red auto',
                                        style: 'red',
                                        cl: 'col'
                                    },
                                    object: {
                                        text: 'blue auto',
                                        style: 'blue',
                                        cl: 'col'
                                    },
                                    object: {
                                        text: 'green auto',
                                        style: 'green',
                                        cl: 'col'
                                    },
                                    object: {
                                        text: 'yellow auto',
                                        style: 'yellow',
                                        cl: 'col'
                                    }

                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
// More below this...
                ]
            }
        })
```

My expected results (from the portion provided):

```
<div id="grid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col" style="background-color: red">red auto</div>
        <div class="col" style="background-color: blue">blue auto</div>
        <div class="col" style="background-color: green">green auto</div>
        <div class="col" style="background-color: yellow">yellow auto</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And what I actually get:

```
<div id="grid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col" style="background-color: yellow">yellow auto</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have 4 properties called `object` in the same object. You can't have duplicates, three of those will just be thrown away. This happens at the JavaScript level, Vue is not involved. Both your rows and columns have a strange `{object: ...}` wrapper that seems unnecessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue that you had is that `v-for="col in item.object.columns"` was returning only one element because your `columns` actually contains only one object filled with invalid data (an object can't have multiple values with same keys the last will stay and the others will get overwritten) .. just remove the `object` keys and use normal objects instead !

```js
var grid = new Vue({
  el: "#grid",
  data: {
    items: [{
      object: {
        columns: [{
            text: 'red auto',
            style: 'red',
            cl: 'col'
          },
          {
            text: 'blue auto',
            style: 'blue',
            cl: 'col'
          },
          {
            text: 'green auto',
            style: 'green',
            cl: 'col'
          },
          {
            text: 'yellow auto',
            style: 'yellow',
            cl: 'col'
          }
        ]
      }
    }]
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="grid">
  <template v-for="item in items">
            <div class="row" v-for="col in item.object.columns">
                <div :class="`${col.cl}`" v-bind:style="{'background-color': `${col.style}`}">{{col.text}}</div>
            </div>
        </template>
</div>
```

Comment: probably want to make the same change to the `items` array as well

Comment: @StephenThomas yes it is better to change that ...i tried changing as less code as he provided